# Make div pull to the right and up with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I made a layout with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). At desktop resolutions it looks like this:

```
+---------------+  +-------------+
|               |  |             |
|       A       |  |             |
|               |  |             |
+---------------+  |             |
|               |  |      C      |
|       B       |  |             |
|               |  |             |
+---------------+  |             |
|               |  |             |
|               |  +-------------+
|               |  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
|       D       |  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
|               |  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
|               |  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
+---------------+  +-------------+
|               |  |             |
|       E       |  |      F      |
|               |  |             |
+---------------+  +-------------+
                   |             |
                   |      G      |
                   |             |
                   +-------------+
```

On mobile devices it looks like this:

```
+---------------+
|               |
|       A       |
|               |
+---------------+
|               |
|       B       |
|               |
+---------------+
|               |
|               |
|       C       |
|               |
|               |
+---------------+
|               |
|               |
|               |
|       D       |
|               |
|               |
+---------------+
|               |
|       E       |
|               |
+---------------+
|               |
|       F       |
|               |
+---------------+
|               |
|       G       |
|               |
+---------------+
```

My problem is that I need to get rid of the space between C and F indicated by the X's.

Here is my markup:
http://pastebin.com/KTJj72Z0

Comment: Your last edit made "Bootstrap" link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144676/make-div-pull-to-the-right-and-up-with-bootstrap, which is this question. Were you perhaps trying to link to http://getbootstrap.com/?

Comment: @Keyslinger what is the breakpoint for mobile version xs, sm, etc

Comment: @MuhammadUmer it goes to 1 column at xs

Answer (score 0):

on div F put negative top margin. It'd pull it above.

like so

```
@media(min-width:768px){
    #F {
       margin-top: -100px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! When I do that, F overlaps D at mobile resolution.